# Subfigures Listed on Wrong Page in Contents Section (package: subcaption)

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats, subcaption, linguistics

I have read through http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf and could not find an answer. There are several questions with similar titles on here, but none of them seem to refer to the problem I am having.

I have three subfigures that I have split across a page, with (a) on page 6 and (b) and (c) on page 7. However, in the toc, it says (a) is on 6, but that (b) and (c) are on 8, which is not the case.

Update: I have edited the code below to include my entire preamble. However, I was able accidentally fix the problem, as I ended up needing to add an additional paragraph before this section that pushed them perfectly onto one page. However, I still have no idea how I would fix the problem should it occur again, so I am leaving it open to find out. Thank you all for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{myfmt}{#1.#2}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=myfmt]{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\title{Phonotactic Effects on the Duration of Word-Initial Aspiration in English}
\author{\Large Noah M. Coen\\[.4cm]{Professor: Dr. Dylan Herrick}\\[.4cm]{Linguistics 3133: Phonetic Field Methods}}
\date{October 8th, 2020}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{HW5Latex.bib}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{\textbf{Waveform Analysis}}
\label{psmethodss}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS1}
\caption{Three Consecutive Utterances}
\label{pstcu}
\end{subfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{flushleft}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS2}
\caption{Single Utterance Selection}
\label{psnsu}
\end{subfigure}
\linebreak
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS3}
\caption{Measurement of Aspiration}
\label{psmad}
\end{subfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: Hello Noah, welcome to Tex.SE! Please make your code compilable, as it currently gives errors. Your code is even lacking a `\documentclass`, and even though it's easy to add one, it doesn't fix really help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong pagenumber in LoF for subfigures added via \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322249/wrong-pagenumber-in-lof-for-subfigures-added-via-input)

Comment: @Alenanno Ah, I'm sorry! I just copied the small portion that was for this specific question. I will edit the question right now and add the entire preamble. Thank you! Sorry again!

Comment: @P.M Unfortunately no :(. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Noah no problem! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in [Wrong pagenumber in LoF for subfigures added via \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322249/wrong-pagenumber-in-lof-for-subfigures-added-via-input) either a "blank" caption or a `\phantomcaption` seems to help here:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, demo]{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{myfmt}{#1.#2}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=myfmt]{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\title{Phonotactic Effects on the Duration of Word-Initial Aspiration in English}
\author{\Large Noah M. Coen\\[.4cm]{Professor: Dr. Dylan Herrick}\\[.4cm]{Linguistics 3133: Phonetic Field Methods}}
\date{October 8th, 2020}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{HW5Latex.bib}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{\textbf{Waveform Analysis}}
\label{psmethodss}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS1}
\caption{Three Consecutive Utterances}
\label{pstcu}
\end{subfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]\ContinuedFloat
\phantomcaption  % <----- This line added
\begin{flushleft}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS2}
\caption{Single Utterance Selection}
\label{psnsu}
\end{subfigure}
\linebreak
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{PSSS3}
\caption{Measurement of Aspiration}
\label{psmad}
\end{subfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Whatever}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Without the `\phantomcaption` the page numbers for the subfigures (b) and (c) are 4 (incorrect), but with `\phantomcaption` the page numbers are 3 (correct).